# Unable to kill process started by Python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

After `start.exe` is executed by Python, the output of `start.exe` is displayed in the python stdout. However 5 seconds later, we do not see `Quitting` printed and the task is not killed.

Is there an easier way to terminate an exe that was originally started by Python? Like getting a handle for the exe executed and using that handle to kill the process.

```
import subprocess
import os
import time

subprocess.call(['.\\start.exe'])

time.sleep(5)
print("Quitting")
os.system("taskkill /im start.exe")
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see at the [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), the `call` function blocks until the process completes.

I believe that you should use the `Popen` functions as it doesn't block, and provides you a process handle.
Then, you can kill it like this: `p.kill()`, where `p` is the result from the `Popen` function.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that [subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) will wait for your `start.exe` to complete before continuing your script.

You can get a [popen object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects)  (with better functionality) to your process via:

```
import subprocess
import os
import time

process = subprocess.Popen(['.\\start.exe'])

time.sleep(5)   
print("Quitting")
process.terminate()
```